# Xamarin ADAL AcquireTokenAsync not returning result! OnActivityResult is hit

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, adal

I have a xamarin.android app and am using ADAL to authenticate.

I have an AuthService that calls

`var authResultAsync = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(...);`

This call never returns an AuthenticationResult object but rather I just hit my OnActivityResult and I am never able to access my token??

```
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated? Am I supposed to access my token a different way?

Comment: Do you refer to this chapter . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-xamarin#step-4-use-adal-to-get-tokens-from-azure-ad

Comment: This is the code flow I am using yes, but my AcquireTokenAsync never returns however it looks like the authentication is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am calling the `AuthenticationContinuationHelper` (MSAL) not `AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper` (ADAL)

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1541