# Xamarin ADAL - AcquireTokenAsync return null result

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.forms, adal

In Xamarin forms Android, I used ADAL library to do AAD login. When call this function AcquireTokenAsync, the result returned is null.

In my MainActivity.cs, I used code below:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I have referenced to this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247957/xamarin-adal-acquiretokenasync-not-returning-result-onactivityresult-is-hit)  by replacing AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper (ADAL) with AuthenticationContinuationHelper (MSAL), but still no hope.

Comment: Are you using ADAL or MSAL? Do you have all the Android components set up correctly? See [this documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Xamarin-Android-specifics) for details. Also, which version of MSAL are you using? Please use the latest MSAL (3.0.6-preview) or ADAL (5.0.3-preview)
Also, can you paste a code snippet of the acquire token call and the creation of the public client? thanks.

Comment: @Jenny, I am using ADAL (v4.5.1). Tried with ADAL (5.0.3-preview) still no hope.
I am referring to this [sample](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directory-login-in-xamarin-forms/) to do my AAD login. Based on this article, no setup is needed for AndroidManifest.xml. Is it only for MSAL, then it is needed to do setup for AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Here's is another Xamarin [sample you can use as a reference](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget)...Could you include above the code you use for creating the AuthenticationContext and the AcquireToken call? Have you tried w/iOS or UWP? thanks.

Comment: @Jenny it is working now. Thanks! But somehow the IdToken that I retrieved after login is incomplete, missing key in the header. Do you have any clue on this?

Comment: Which value are you looking for in the IdToken? What did you do to get it working?

Comment: @Jenny, its my careless mistake that causing it. I am passing through IdToken generated from my AAD App to another AAD App to do authentication. Both AAD Apps are under same domain. However the IdToken that passed through hit "No key found in header".

Comment: Can you provide some more details on your exact scenario? thx.